# Doubly Stochastic Transformation Using Python

Tags: python, matrix, transformation

Give a matrix `X={xij}`, I want to transform this matrix into a doubly stochastic matrix whose each row and each column sums to 1.

How can I do that using a matrix to a doubly stochastic matrix using python?

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"? What properties of the original matrix do you need to preserve?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi! I see you've edited your question to add the definition of a doubly stochastic matrix. That's nice. But it still doesn't say what you mean by "transform". Obviously, if you start with a matrix M which is not doubly stochastic, then end with a doubly stochastic matrix P, then M and P will be two different matrices. But surely you want P to somehow "represent" the same thing that M represented? Without more context, it's hard to know what you want.

Comment: My point is that, if you take a matrix M, and hit it hard enough with a hammer, it's always possible to end with a doubly stochastic matrix. But possibly the doubly stochastic matrix you get at the end is very different from M. And there are different possible ways to do that transformation. You need to give more context on where this matrix comes from and why you need it to be doubly stochastic.

Comment: I am trying to implement the algorithm of this paper: https://www.pnas.org/content/106/26/E66

Comment: It says in the abstract *"In the first stage, the N row and N column sums of the N × N matrix of weighted, directed network flows (fij) are alternately scaled to all equal 1, iteratively, until sufficient convergence to a doubly stochastic table is attained."*

Comment: So it sounds as if they don't actually get a doubly-stochastic matrix, just something *sufficient*ly close to a double-stochastic matrix.

Comment: Scaling the rows to get a row-stochastic matrix is easy. Scaling the columns to get a column-stochastic matrix is easy. Apparently they're scaling the rows, then scaling the columns, then scaling the rows again, then scaling the columns again, etc